# Iteratively writing to a file in Python, creating a new string in each iteration

Tags: python

I'm missing the obvious, I think, but I'd be grateful to someone who points it out. It's been an hour of playing with syntax and I'm frustrated.

The following is an MWE. It takes less than 1 second to run:

```
from itertools import product

PARAM_GRID = list(product(
range(64, 68),
range(64, 68),
range(132, 136),
range(132, 136),
))

SCOREFILE = './fake_scores.csv'

def search_distributed():

    for param_ix in range(len(PARAM_GRID)):

        params = PARAM_GRID[param_ix]
        score = 0.9

        with open(SCOREFILE, 'a') as f:
            #NOT MINE, and doesn't do what I want
            #f.write('{",".join(map(str, params + (score,)))}\n')

            #MINE, and still doesn't do what I want.
            paramstr = str(params) 
            scorestr = str(score) 
            f.write("\n".join({paramstr + ' ' + scorestr}))

def main():
    search_distributed()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Instead of what this creates, which is a file containing:

```
(64, 64, 132, 132) 0.9(64, 64, 132, 133) 0.9(64, 64, 132, 134) 0.9...
```

I want a file containing:

```
(64, 64, 132, 132) 0.9
(64, 64, 132, 133) 0.9
(64, 64, 132, 134) 0.9
```

Obviously I need to modify the `join` command somehow. I've shown my attempt above. Can anyone fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small tweak of your code to solve your issue :

```
from itertools import product

PARAM_GRID = list(product(
range(64, 68),
range(64, 68),
range(132, 136),
range(132, 136),
))

SCOREFILE = './fake_scores.csv'

def search_distributed():

    for param_ix in range(len(PARAM_GRID)):

        params = PARAM_GRID[param_ix]
        score = 0.9

        with open(SCOREFILE, 'a') as f:
            #NOT MINE, and doesn't do what I want
            #f.write('{",".join(map(str, params + (score,)))}\n')

            #MINE, and still doesn't do what I want.
            paramstr = str(params) 
            scorestr = str(score) 
            f.write(paramstr + ' ' + scorestr + '\n')

def main():
    search_distributed()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As your are giving only one element (`{paramstr + ' ' + scorestr}` is only one string, not an list of elements) to the `join` method, it doesn't add any "\n". You just need to manually add it to the end of each one of your lines.